# How can I add a for each inside of another for each in Yii2?

Tags: php, html, yii2

Well what I want to do is in the first for each -which is done- to retrieve data from the model preguntas and with previous information I want to generate for each data a radiolist.

In case you don't understand, what I'm trying to do is 
For each Questions(Preguntas) found in model Preguntas generate a HTML label, and for each label done generate a radiolist with five buttons.

```php
?php use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use unclead\multipleinput\MultipleInput;
use app\models\Preguntas;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use yii\db\Query;
use app\models\Respuestas;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */


/* @var $model app\models\Encuestas */


/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

?> <div class="encuestas-form"> <?php $form=ActiveForm::begin();
?> <?=$form->field($model, 'titulo')->textInput(['maxlength'=> true]) ?> <?=$form->field($model, 'objetivo')->textInput(['maxlength'=> true]) ?> <?php $respuestas=Respuestas::find()->all();
?> <?php foreach (Preguntas::find()->all() as $pregunta) {
    $data=$pregunta->preguntas;
    echo "<br>";
    echo Html: : label( $data, 'Pregunta', ['class'=> 'control-label', 'style'=> 'color:black']);
    echo "<br>";
    foreach ((array)$data as $respuesta) {
        echo Html: : radio('agree', true, ['label'=> 'I agree', 'value'=> '1']);
        ;
        echo Html: : radio('agree', true, ['label'=> 'I agree', 'value'=> '2']);
        ;
    }
}

?> <div class="form-group"> <?=Html::submitButton( $model->isNewRecord ? 'Create': 'Update', ['class'=> $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success': 'btn btn-primary'])?> </div> <?php ActiveForm::end();
?> </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Currently you do an foreach within an foreach so what is the problem? And plz show only relvant code, thnx

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Well they are two problems. 1) It prints in a vertical way(i tried to use inline() but didn't work) but i want it in a horizontal way 2) How i can "point" it to another model

Comment: Not sure you even need the second for each - have you looked at Html::radioList, using ArrayHelper::map to generate the items?